# Signature/Hash Choice for File Integrity Verification

Tags: security, hash, sha

For a file repository, I need to select a hashing algorithm that will reasonably ensure the integrity of files.

I need an algorithm that anyone (with a bit of effort) would be able to easily use to verify the integrity given the hash. In short, the file may be transferred to the user, along with a hash, and they must be able to verify that the hash comes from the file.

My first choice would be MD5 because there seems to be widely available utilities to verify MD5 hashes, but I'm concerned with the MD5 algorithm being cryptographically broken (ref Wikipedia/US-CERT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

My second choice would be a SHA-2 algorithm, but I'm concerned about availability of utilities that could easily verify the hash. Most examples I've found show program code to evaluate a hash, but I've found few, if any, utilities that are pre-built (asking users to build their own utility is beyond the 'easily' scope)

What other options are available for generating and evaluating a file hash, or are these two the options that are best?

Comment: In this context second pre-image seems to be the relevant attack. There is no known way to efficiently find second pre-images for MD5.

Comment: @CodesInChaos define efficiently. If it can be done inefficiently, isn't that still a concern.

Comment: @weston In this case it's >2^120 MD5 invocations, i.e. totally infeasible.

Comment: Second pre-image attack has been done. Because of inherent weaknesses in the algorithm, you can no longer rely on MD5 requiring its theoretical maximum. That's what is meant when people say MD5 is cryptographically 'broken'. http://th.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/people/lucks/HashCollisions/ These attacks rely on being able to pad their corrupted data with arbitrary data to force a collision.

Comment: @CodesInChaos please explain "in this case it's >2^120" What infomation are you basing that on from the question?

Comment: @kander There is an academic second pre-image attack on MD5, but it's infeasible in practice(>2^120). Collision attacks on the the other hand are practical.

Comment: @weston I don't get your question. I only said that second pre-images on MD5 requires more than 2^120 MD5 invocations, which certainly isn't efficient.

Comment: @CodesInChaos OK, it was the "in this case" part of your comment I didn't understand. I didn't get why this case was special. But you mean in any/all MD5 cases.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The research I linked to describes a very feasible 2nd Pre-Image attack. Perhaps you've only read as far as the title (since title only mentions collision)? The article describes creating a second cleartext (a letter of recommendation vs a security clearance), both yielding the same MD5 hash, by applying Wang & Yu's method for creating a collision by using non-visible data. This has been successfully applied in both binaries and documents. Seems highly relevant when validating downloaded files...

Comment: People, thank you for your input, but as this is turning into a discussion about whether an algorithm is broken, not which options exist, I'm going to ask that we don't keep commenting about the former.

Comment: As a follow-up, I went with @weston's approach and have already implemented both MD5 and SHA512 as options and will present both to the user with links to download tools to verify both hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide both/multiple, and let the user decide which they verify against. Or if they are really cautious, they can verify against both/all.

Have seen download sites use this approach. One site recommended the most secure, but offered others like md5 as fallback. It also provided links to tools. Can't remember specific site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've been able to find a few file-checkers, why not link to them as a recommendation? That way your users have at least one tool they can use. They don't need several dozen different filechecking utilities, they need just one which works for the algo you chose to use.

Tools you could link to:
Windows: http://securityxploded.com/download-hash-verifier.php
Mac OS X: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31781/checksum

Comment: Which in turn requires trusting these programs

Comment: +1'ed your comment because it is something to be aware of. However, if you follow that line of reasoning, you'll need users to write their own compilers... it's trust all the way down.

Comment: I'm comfortable recommending users to use a pre-built utility for convenience, and those that need additional security will also know how to ensure that security using their own tools. Users are estimated to be 95% 'I do not care about file integrity' and the rest mixed with 'may I will check' and 'I will build my own tool to verify'.

Comment: And @kander, I will definitely link to suggested tools, if nothing else on a help page. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

`sha256sum`, a program a part of the `coreutils` package on linux will generate checksums for the listed files. The format of the checksum output is the same as that of the `md5sum` program (but using SHA-256 hashing instead of MD5 of course), which has been widely used for years. You didn't list any target platforms but a quick googling shows there are Windows ports of the command line program.

If you need to generate large numbers of checksums you can use md5deep, which includes support for other hashes as well, including SHA-256.
http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/

I haven't tried this but from the screenshots it looks pretty neat integrating into OSX and Windows Explorer: http://implbits.com/HashTab.aspx

Comment: HashTab looks very nice, I'll definitely add this to the list of tools. I didn't find it in my original search either, so my Google skillz must suck...